# Using openCV template matcher, in the absence of the desired object, in any case, finds a match. How to get an exception?

Tags: java, opencv, automated-tests

I need to check the logo on the bank card. Is it possible to fix my code in such a way that when the logo doesn't match, the system does not search for a similar element, but throws out the exception?

I'm trying to change the variables in the threshold method, but with no result.

```
  private static void isTemplateImageExist(String sourceScreenshotPath,
                                                 String sourceScreenshot,
                                                 String templateScreenshotPath,
                                                 String templateImage,
                                                 String resultImage){
            CustomLogger.info("Getting images for comparing");
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            Mat source = Highgui.imread(sourceScreenshotPath + sourceScreenshot, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
            Mat template = Highgui.imread(templateScreenshotPath + templateImage);
            Mat outputImage = new Mat();
            int machMethod = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;
            CustomLogger.info("Comparing images");
            //Template matching method
            Imgproc.threshold(source, outputImage, 1, 250, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
            Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, template, outputImage, machMethod);
            drawRectangleOnResultImage(outputImage,source,template,sourceScreenshotPath,resultImage);
        }
```

I want to see an exception if logo doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `outputImage` to get min and max values. Check if max value is greater than some desired threshold. If max value is not greater than that threshold `throw` an `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's will be helpful for somebody. Thanks for idea Elvis Oric. I take a coordinates of good matching and comparing them with took coordinates. Before that I made a constant of good matching.

```
private static String LOGO_POINTS_FOR_MY_CARDS_SCREEN = "{231.0, 248.0}";

private static boolean isCardsLogoExistForMyCardsScreen(String sourceScreenshotPath,
                                                        String sourceScreenshot,
                                                        String templateScreenshotPath,
                                                        String templateImage,
                                                        String resultImage){
    CustomLogger.info("Getting images for comparing");
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat source = Highgui.imread(sourceScreenshotPath + sourceScreenshot, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat template = Highgui.imread(templateScreenshotPath + templateImage);
    Mat outputImage = new Mat();
    int machMethod = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;
    CustomLogger.info("Comparing images");
    //Template matching method
    Imgproc.threshold(source, outputImage, TRESH, TRESH_MAX_VALUE, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, template, outputImage, machMethod);
    drawRectangleOnResultImage(outputImage,source,template,sourceScreenshotPath,resultImage);
    CustomLogger.info("Comparing points of images");
    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(outputImage);
    Point matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    String points = (new Point(matchLoc.x + template.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + template.rows())).toString();
    if (points.equals(LOGO_POINTS_FOR_MY_CARDS_SCREEN)){
        CustomLogger.info("The matching is found");
        return true;
    } else {
        CustomLogger.info("There is no matching");
        return false;
    }
}
```